# GROUP BY respecting before and after values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table of coordinates (of user's trajectory) with country codes and I have my data ordered by date.

```
user,coordinates, country
1, place1, US
1. place2, US
1, place3, UK
1, place4, UK
1, place1, US
2, place5, US
2, place6, US
2, place7, US
2, place8, US
```

I want to get movement country sequence like this

```
1x "US, UK, US" ;
1x "US",
```

When I do GROUP BY I just get seq1 as "US,UK". I need to have these unique values in the sequence to know where the user moved. Is there something like version of group by which is respecting the previous and next rows in this sorted sequence?

Comment: You need a column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a column that specifies the ordering, so let me assume that one exists.

```
select user, string_agg(country, ', ' order by ??) as countries
from (select t.*,
             lag(country) over (partition by user order by ??) as prev_country
      from t
     ) t
where prev_country is null or country <> prev_country;
```

Just specify the correct column for ordering where the `??` is.